# What is the difference between fixed path and relative path?

Tags: xml, flash, swfobject

I am displaying some flash content on a fairly standard page. This works really well when the flash, xml file and html page are sitting together in the same directory.

See working example: http://www.rouviere.com/flipbook/

However, I want to display that same content in another page which is deeper inside the site but outside of the directory that houses the .swf and .xml files as well as the assets.

Here is the page that I would like the content to show up properly on: http://www.rouviere.com/writing/books

Here are the parameters that I have set:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../flipbook/swfobject.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../flipbook/swfaddress.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {
xmlPath:          '../../flipbook/setup.xml',
preloaderMessage: 'LOADING XML',
title:            'Books | Rouviere Media' 
};

var params = {};
var attributes = {id:'flipbook', name:'flipbook'};
params.scale = "noscale";
params.salign = "tl";
params.bgcolor = "0x000000";
params.allowfullscreen = "true";
params.allowScriptAccess = "always";

swfobject.embedSWF("../../flipbook/preview.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

The js files are loading properly but the flash content is not, so I could use a little help getting that sorted out.

Thanks.

Comment: When visiting your second link I get an unhandled IO Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML path should probably be written as relative to the location of the SWF, assuming that it's the SWF that will load it.  Otherwise give everything absolute URLs from the web root starting with `/`.

Comment: If this doesn't  solve it, I would throw some trace statements in your code, then use something like [Flashbug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashbug/) to see them in your browser. Find out where it's failing.